# Path Lengths on a Sphere example.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

What does $\rho$ mean as to be measured along geodesics and more importantly how would i be able to parametrize this accordingly as being on the sphere's surface?

I know that I have to use the First fundamental Form, but struggle to use it as well............the path is in 3-D space (ie, great circle).

So how can I get around this? As a result of not being able to figure out the usage of $\rho$ I am unable to do part c). Finding the area.

[image]

Comment: $\rho$ is measured along great circles means that you are interested in a spherical circle, i.e. you look at all points on $S^2$ having geodesic distance $\rho$ from a fixed point on the sphere. This is going to be a circle of Eucildean radius $<\rho$. As an example: The circle of radius $\pi/2$ around the north pole is exactly the equator which has Euclidean radius 1.

Comment: So geodesic distance of radius $\rho$ doesn't necessarily imply that it is a great circle of the sphere? but more it implies that it is a geodesic of radius $\rho$. Of radius $\pi/2$ around the north pole means when viewed from the top looks like a dot (north-pole) with a circle around it (geodesic)?

Comment: Exactly: The circle is a great circle iff its radius is $\pi/2$. What do you mean by "a geodesic of radius $\rho$"? Geodesics on the sphere are always parts of great circles.

Comment: I thought the geodesic had $r=1$ perhaps my idea of great circles is incorrect? ah nevermind about that part! How did you attain the radius of $\pi/2$ for the circle again?

Comment: I think there is a problem with mixing up geodesic and Euclidean distances: You can think of a great circle (after rotation if needed) as being the equator. The equator of a unit sphere has Euclidean radius one. However, if one regards this same circle as being a circle on the sphere with midpoint one of the poles, then the geodesic radius is given by the distance of the equator from the poles (which is $\pi/2$ as the full circumference of a great circle is $2\pi$).

Comment: ahh that makes sense now! as in we can imagine having a sticker of a circle and sticking it to the surface of a sphere? So border line of that sticker on the sphere is the geodesic.